# Como definir propriedades padrão para variável que começarem com um texto especifico?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-first, fluent-api

Existe alguma forma de definir as propriedades de uma variável como padrão pela iniciais da variáveis?

Algo como `public string obsUsuario { get; set; }`, todas que começarem com **obs** ter como padrão a propriedade `IsOptional`, (ou/e outras propriedades) sem ter que ficar declarando toda vez para cada uma variável?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Usuarios>().Property(prop => prop.obsUsuario).IsOptional();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Só precisa usar um pouco de *reflection*

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
        .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("descr"))
        .Configure(p => p.IsOptional());
```

Comment: Legal, posso até usar um `||` aqui para mais campos . tipo `.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("descr") || p.Name.StartsWith("obs"))`, isso vai me ajudar muito. Vlw